# I created a custom cursor, it worked fine but when i scroll on webpage the cursor loses position

Tags: html, jquery, css

Once I scroll on the webpage my cursor loses position...Someone should please help out. THANKS

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  // values: e.clientX, e.clientY, e.pageX, e.pageY
  $(".cursor-custom").css({
    left: e.clientX - 10,
    top: e.clientY - 10,
  });
});
```

```css
.cursor-custom {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* z-index: ; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor-custom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `position` `absolute` to `fixed`.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $(".cursor-custom").css({
    left: e.clientX - 10,
    top: e.clientY - 10,
  });
});
```

```css
body { height: 300vh; } /* Just for demonstration */

.cursor-custom {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor-custom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the position needs to be changed to "fixed", but also the end value needs to be a measurement that css is familiar with, i.e., 10px, not just a number. Using a template literal, you can perform the calculation and insert the final evaluation with the measurement of choice, in your case "px". For example:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  // values: e.clientX, e.clientY, e.pageX, e.pageY
  $(".cursor-custom").css({
    left: `${e.clientX - 10}px`,
    top: `${e.clientY - 10}px`,
  });
});
```

```css
.cursor-custom {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  /* top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* z-index: ; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor-custom"></div>
```